# Visual studio 2010 reporting "Access violation" for Oracle OCCI 11g when creating connection

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, oracle

When I tried to create a connection with Oracle OCCI 11g on Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, I got below error:

Unhandled exception at 0x005a79c9 in OracleOCCI.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x316c6561.

My code is very simple as below:

```
class DMLDemo
{
private:

    Environment *env;
    Connection *conn;
    Statement *stmt;

public:

    DMLDemo (string user, string passwd, string db)
    {
        env = Environment::createEnvironment (Environment::DEFAULT);
        if(env==nullptr)
            cout << "Failure";


            try
            {
                conn = env->createConnection (user, passwd, db);
        }
            catch (exception* e)
            {
                cout << "Error";
            }


    }

    ~DMLDemo ()
    {
        env->terminateConnection (conn);
        Environment::terminateEnvironment (env);
    }

};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    //01. Test Simple Connection
    try
    {
        DMLDemo demo("scott","Michael1","");
    }
    catch (exception* e)
    {
        cout << e->what();

    }

    getche();


    return 0;
}
```

I googled for some answers, seems that something is wrong with the compatibility between oracle dll version and the VC version.

Anyone who has a solution for this? Or just change to VS 2005?

Comment: [Does this help?](http://thisthread.blogspot.de/2011/07/oracle-occi-for-visual-studio-2010.html) Make sure you are using the correct occi dll/lib for your system (correct Compiler Version and 32/64 bit)

Comment: Yes, it compiles all right. And it can successfuly run the createEnvironment call, it only pops error when it comes to env->createConnection (user, passwd, db)...

Comment: [check this page for the correct occi version](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/occidownloads-083553.html). Are you sure that the correct dll is loaded (some old oracle dlls in your search path could cause trouble). I only had this problem with a version mismatch. Can you catch any exception, or does it just exit? What is the exception text, if any?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can't catch any exception, it just exit with the error message. "Unhandled exception at 0x01c879c9 in OracleOCCI.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x316c6561." I only have Oracle 11g r2 DLL's referenced should be ok. I guess maybe the reason is with vs2010. Anyone used Vs2010 for OCCI programming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been building VS08 and VS10 interfaces to the Oracle 11g( 11.2.0) 32 bit database. I found that a number of the sites providing occi11x.dlls, including my own Oracle installation, delivered in the V9 directory,  were not compatible with the VS08 console app. Finally, I had to have the tested 'gold' binaries delivered to me from another location in the company. Once the x86 'gold' dll was installed in the console launch directory, the very same code functioned properly.

I am searching for the same suitability in VS10 occi11x.dlls. As yet I haven't found it. I am getting similar faults following the Environment creation. Some dlls allow me to make a connection but fault when I try to do a ResultSet->next(), others won't allow me even to do the executeQuery(). I think Oracle is remiss in not managing this properly.

The 'broken' VS08 dlls sometimes had the correct dates and file size as the 'gold' dlls. Perhaps an internal search of the dlls will discover which ones are workable.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/occidownloads-083553.html is the site that oracle uses to supply various occi dlls to match to Visual Studio. Perhaps their VS12 version is actually more compatible with the Oracle12c database.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, finally I installed VS 2008 and the code works out all right. Seems that the Oracle DLL compiled in 2008 would not work in VS2010.

Maybe someday, Oracle can publish its VS2010 Dlls...